# Keycloak empty h2 database

Tags: keycloak

From what I was able to find around the internet the h2(default) Keycloak database in dev mode is saved under the data folder of my user: on windows "C:\Users\[*UserName*]\data\keycloakdb.mv", so I used h2-console to log into that file but it just seem to be an empty h2 database with no other tables than the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

[image]

**Where does keycloak store information such as realms,users,clients etc?** and where can I access it ?

Comment: Did you find your answer or did you give up? I am confused as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I think you are not actually opening the real DB, but instead a newly created one. Some things to check:

1. Also try shutting down Keycloak before opening it, there might be some locking issue.
2. Also do you use the correct credentials? For me it was

   ```
   user: sa
   password: password
   ```
3. The url probably needs to look something like
   `jdbc:h2:C:\Users\[UserName]\data\keycloakdb`

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC url should not include .mv.db as below:

jdbc:h2:\data\h2\keycloakdb

Then login using username sa, password is password.

Note: i'm using keycloak-22.0.3